# Why isn't a String an Enum?

Tags: haskell

Why is `[Char]` an instance of `Ord`, but not of `Enum`?

```
Prelude> let succ_a = "a" ++ [minBound::Char]
Prelude> "a" < succ_a
True
Prelude> succ_a < "a "
True
Prelude> succ_a < succ_a ++ [minBound::Char]
True
```

I think there's no String between "a" and `succ_a` - so why not `succ "a" == succ_a`?

Comment: Actually, I can think of many strings between "a" and "aa". There's "a_", and "a__", "a____", and "a______ " ... ad infinitum. ("_" is supposed to be a space, btw)

Comment: Point taken.  But see the edit - "a" ++ [minBound::Char] - which is "a\NULL" - is > "a" and < any of these examples

Comment: The `Enum` instance you're proposing isn't useful. Enumerating starting at a given value would just produce a stream of ever-longer strings of `\NULL` characters, and no `Enum` instance can be proposed which is useful for the same reason the real numbers are not recursively enumerable.

Comment: Note that the annotation `::Char` is unnecessary here, it'll be inferred. A more interesting question would be why lists aren't an instance of Bounded, but the answer is probably "no-one has ever needed that instance".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since strings are lists in Haskell, you might as well ask why lists aren't in `Enum`, since you wouldn't be able to write an instance for just strings without extensions. But that doesn't matter. The problem is that **enumeration in lexicographical order isn't very useful**, since you just keep appending the smallest character at the end indefinitely.

Using the alphabet `a..z` for simplicity, lexicographical order just gives us repetitions of the first letter.

```
"", "a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa" ...
```

The more useful order for enumerating strings is by length. This way, we first get the empty string, then all the strings of length 1, then all of length 2, etc.

```
"", "a", "b", ... "z", "aa", "ba", ... "za", "ab", ... "zz", "aaa", "baa" ...
```

This is essentially the same as enumerating integers, with the digits reversed, so when you get to `"zz"` you carry and get `"aaa"`, just like how you get from 99 to 100.

However, this would be inconsistent with the `Ord` instance for lists which uses the lexicographical ordering.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I don't know much about Haskell.

However, it seems from http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Enum that an Enum has to support toEnum and fromEnum to convert from the enum type to Int and back again. How would this work for strings? If `succ_a = "a" ++ [minBound::Char]`, then any Int maps onto a string "a" with some number of `minBound::Char`'s appended to it (or more realistically, any Int `n` maps onto a list of size `n` which contains only `minBound::Char`). So, "b" would not map onto any Int.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're wrong about "a" and "aa":

```
Prelude> "a" < "aA" && "aA" < "aa"
True
```

What's the next string after "foo"? Is it "fop"? Is it "fooa?" Is it "foo\0"?

Comment: Actually I think it's `"foo" ++ [minBound::Char]`.